Where can I get additional *console* (ie. virtual-terminal) fonts? Or convert other font formats?
Where can I get/download additional Console / Virtual-Terminal (on F1 through F6) fonts - especially larger ones?  I'm here talking about the font that can be set with the setfont command.  Also, are there any tools letting me convert other font-formats (like TrueType) to the format used by the console/setfont (I guess assuming it's a fixed-width font)?

I only know Terminus. Fedora doesn't offer anything else either.

setfont loads PSF ("PC Screen Font", a rather archaic format, which is logical – you're interfacing with the emulation of a 40 years old hardware console) fonts, or, much preferably, PSFU (PSF with Unicode mappings).

(I know that because I read the man setfont manual – you should, too, if you haven't!)
By default, it looks into /usr/lib/kbd/consolefonts ; you'll already find a lot of (potentially compressed) psfu fonts there. In my case, that's
$> ls usr/lib/kbd/consolefonts
Agafari-12.psfu.gz      gr737b-9x16-medieval.psfu.gz  lat1-14.psfu.gz          lat9u-12.psfu.gz
Agafari-14.psfu.gz      gr737c-8x14.psfu.gz           lat1-16.psfu.gz          lat9u-14.psfu.gz
Agafari-16.psfu.gz      gr737c-8x16.psfu.gz           lat2-08.psfu.gz          lat9u-16.psfu.gz
cp1250.psfu.gz          gr737c-8x6.psfu.gz            lat2-10.psfu.gz          lat9v-08.psfu.gz
cp850-8x14.psfu.gz      gr737c-8x7.psfu.gz            lat2-12.psfu.gz          lat9v-10.psfu.gz
cp850-8x16.psfu.gz      gr737c-8x8.psfu.gz            lat2-14.psfu.gz          lat9v-12.psfu.gz
cp850-8x8.psfu.gz       gr737d-8x16.psfu.gz           lat2-16.psfu.gz          lat9v-14.psfu.gz
cp865-8x14.psfu.gz      gr928-8x16-thin.psfu.gz       lat2a-16.psfu.gz         lat9v-16.psfu.gz
cp865-8x16.psfu.gz      gr928-9x14.psfu.gz            lat2-sun16.psfu.gz       lat9w-08.psfu.gz
cp865-8x8.psfu.gz       gr928-9x16.psfu.gz            Lat2-Terminus16.psfu.gz  lat9w-10.psfu.gz
Cyr_a8x14.psfu.gz       gr928a-8x14.psfu.gz           lat4-08.psfu.gz          lat9w-12.psfu.gz
Cyr_a8x16.psfu.gz       gr928a-8x16.psfu.gz           lat4-10.psfu.gz          lat9w-14.psfu.gz
Cyr_a8x8.psfu.gz        gr928b-8x14.psfu.gz           lat4-12.psfu.gz          lat9w-16.psfu.gz
cyr-sun16.psfu.gz       gr928b-8x16.psfu.gz           lat4-14.psfu.gz          LatArCyrHeb-08.psfu.gz
default8x16.psfu.gz     greek-polytonic.psfu.gz       lat4-16.psfu.gz          LatArCyrHeb-14.psfu.gz
default8x9.psfu.gz      iso01-12x22.psfu.gz           lat4-16+.psfu.gz         LatArCyrHeb-16.psfu.gz
drdos8x14.psfu.gz       iso02-12x22.psfu.gz           lat4-19.psfu.gz          LatArCyrHeb-16+.psfu.gz
drdos8x16.psfu.gz       iso07u-16.psfu.gz             lat4a-08.psfu.gz         LatArCyrHeb-19.psfu.gz
drdos8x6.psfu.gz        koi8r.8x8.psfu.gz             lat4a-10.psfu.gz         latarcyrheb-sun16.psfu.gz
drdos8x8.psfu.gz        koi8u_8x14.psfu.gz            lat4a-12.psfu.gz         latarcyrheb-sun32.psfu.gz
eurlatgr.psfu.gz        koi8u_8x16.psfu.gz            lat4a-14.psfu.gz         LatGrkCyr-12x22.psfu.gz
Goha-12.psfu.gz         koi8u_8x8.psfu.gz             lat4a-16.psfu.gz         LatGrkCyr-8x16.psfu.gz
Goha-14.psfu.gz         lat0-08.psfu.gz               lat4a-16+.psfu.gz        LatKaCyrHeb-14.psfu.gz
Goha-16.psfu.gz         lat0-10.psfu.gz               lat4a-19.psfu.gz         pancyrillic.f16.psfu.gz
GohaClassic-12.psfu.gz  lat0-12.psfu.gz               lat5-12.psfu.gz          ruscii_8x16.psfu.gz
GohaClassic-14.psfu.gz  lat0-14.psfu.gz               lat5-14.psfu.gz          ruscii_8x8.psfu.gz
GohaClassic-16.psfu.gz  lat0-16.psfu.gz               lat5-16.psfu.gz          solar24x32.psfu.gz
gr737a-8x8.psfu.gz      lat0-sun16.psfu.gz            lat7-14.psfu.gz          sun12x22.psfu.gz
gr737a-9x14.psfu.gz     lat1-08.psfu.gz               lat7a-14.psfu.gz         viscii10-8x16.psfu.gz
gr737a-9x16.psfu.gz     lat1-10.psfu.gz               lat9u-08.psfu.gz
gr737b-8x11.psfu.gz     lat1-12.psfu.gz               lat9u-10.psfu.gz

There's also a README in that directory for most of these font families!
All from the kbd-misc package of fedora (pretty certain you have the same if you're on x86, but depending on your linux distro, which I don't know, it might be called differently).
Asking my (fedora-specific) package manager about other packages that install things in that directory should yield a comprehensive list of what my distro ships in such font packages:
$> dnf5 repoquery --file=/usr/lib/kbd/consolefonts/\*                                                                                                 
Updating and loading repositories:
Repositories loaded.
cmatrix-0:2.0-6.fc39.x86_64
kbd-misc-0:2.6.3-1.fc39.noarch
terminus-fonts-console-0:4.49.1-23.fc39.noarch

Let's go through this:

cmatrix is just an emulation of the Matrix movie (surprisingly little linear algebra in that), and it brings a font that you won't be able to use for anything else,
kbd-misc contains all the fonts, you already have that
terminus-fonts-console contains, well, the Terminus font family. This might be what you're after. Again, the name of that package depends on your Linux distro, and we don't know which you have.


Also, are there any tools letting me convert other font-formats (like TrueType) to the format used by the console/setfont (I guess assuming it's a fixed-width font)?

It's not only a fixed-width font, it's a bitmap font with a bit-depth of 1 bit, which is so fundamentally different than a TrueType/OpenType/Type1 vector… font, that it is not inherently so that you can just convert a curves-based font, like TrueType fonts are, to it: at the low resolution of the console fonts, these fonts don't "work" in monochrome (they become illegible, because they assume you can draw with higher resolution and anti-aliasing. nope.).
So, you need to convert a bitmap font to the PSF format, and supply a unicode mapping table (because your virtual terminal needs to know what glyph to show when the output asks it to show µ (U+00B5, "MICRO SIGN"), or even just A (U+0041 "LATIN CAPITAL LETTER A"). That's thoroughly possible, let's ask our package manager for choices (dnf5 search PSF), which yields bdf2psf and psftools.
I have tried neither. But:

bdf2psf converts BDF fonts to PSF (surprise). BDF is the old Adobe bitmap font format from 1987. Great! Fits the period of the hardware you want to interface a simulation of with. There's a TrueType-to-BDF conversion tool (ttf2bdf) if you know that a monospace TrueType font looks especially well when scaled really tiny and with 1 bit color depth.
psftools seems to be more aimed at people who want to rescue their DOS/Windows 3.1/… fonts for their Linux console. Nice, but ultimately: means that you get fonts that will feel very incomplete by modern standards and you might need to hand-tweak the unicode mapping (because, of course, MS DOS fonts etc have no notion of "yeah, there's more characters than the 127 of the codepage I care about").

TL;DR
You might be looking for the "Terminus Console Fonts" package; if that gives you nothing you want to work with, you'll have to convert your own bitmap fonts. Good luck in that case!
Conclusion
There's good reasons why people prefer to work on consoles in graphical terminal emulators instead of a emulated VGA/EGA console; fonts is clearly chief among the quality differences.
